# Protocol extension and addTarget is crashing with NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, swift

Protocol extension and addTarget is crashing with message: **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Test.UIButton touchDown:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x157eee8e0'**

Where is the problem that touchDown function is unrecognized?

```
protocol MyButtonProtocol {
    var holdTimer: NSTimer? { get set }
}
extension MyButtonProtocol where Self: UIButton {
    func enable() {
        addTarget(self, action: "touchDown:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
    }
    mutating func touchDown(sender: UIButton) {
        print("Touch down!")
        holdTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: Selector("didTimeOut"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
// Usage:
let button = UIButton()
button.enable()
```

Comment: `UIButton` doesn't conform to `MyButtonProtocol` ?

Comment: This looks like a bug. Also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31060365/swift-2-protocol-extensions-respondstoselector Or is it a feature? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431753/swift-protocol-extensions-overriding

Comment: Everyone is confused by this. Here's another one: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-544 . So, Methods from protocol extensions are not usable with objective-C calls, like anything that uses "Selector". Thanks for pursuing this, Ramis, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is all very odd.

Your code

```
let button = UIButton()
button.enable()
```

seems incomplete, because the instance `button` is not adopting the protocol `MyButtonProtocol`.

If I write

```
class MyButton: UIButton, MyButtonProtocol {
    var holdTimer: NSTimer?
    func touch3(sender: AnyObject?) {
        print("touch3 \(sender)")
    }
}
```

then

```
let myButton = MyButton()
myButton.enable() // this works ok
print("touch3: \(myButton.respondsToSelector(Selector("touch3:")))")
print("touchDown: \(myButton.respondsToSelector(Selector("touchDown:")))")
print("enable \(myButton.respondsToSelector(Selector("enable")))")
```

then I see the output

```
touch3: true
touchDown: false
enable false
```

so the program is successfully calling the `enable()` method but `respondsToSelector` does not seem to be checking the methods in the protocol extension. `enable` is working because if I change the call to

```
addTarget(self, action: "touch3:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
```

then that does successfully reach `touch3`.

Is that a bug in the implementation of `NSObject.respondsToSelector`?

I did notice a couple of weeks ago that I could not override a function in `super` with a function in a protocol extension. I thought it was just a language feature I misunderstood. Maybe that was another symptom of the same problem?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I did more testing without luck. I asked Apple team about this behavior. I will keep posting.

Comment: Answer from the Apple: Engineering has determined that this issue behaves as intended based on the following information: Swift protocol extensions are not available to Objective-C. Only extensions to classes can be used by Objective-C.

We are now closing this bug report.

Answer (score 0):

```
protocol MyButtonProtocol {
    var holdTimer: NSTimer? { get set }
}
extension MyButtonProtocol where Self: UIButton {
    var holdTimer: NSTimer? {
        get {
            return holdTimer
        }
        set {
            holdTimer = newValue;
        }
    }

    func enable() {
        addTarget(self, action: "touchDown:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
    }
    mutating func touchDown(sender: UIButton) {
        print("Touch down!")
        holdTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: Selector("didTimeOut"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}

extension UIButton: MyButtonProtocol {
}

// Usage:
let button = UIButton()
button.enable()
```

Notice the extension written for UIButton, this is needed since you have written a protocol but UIButton needs to implement it inorder for it to be effective. I have also written the getter and setter for `holdTimer` in the protocol extension. You can also write this inside the `UIButton` extension.

Comment: `myButton.respondsToSelector(Selector("touchDown:"))` still returns `false` with this implementation and it still gives an exception on the call to `touchDown`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from the Apple Bug Report Team:

> Engineering has determined that this issue behaves as intended based
>   on the following information: Swift protocol extensions are not
>   available to Objective-C. Only extensions to classes can be used by
>   Objective-C.